# Distinct in update query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I want to update distinct emp number to users in the table.
In table there are many records for single user, so need to update same emp num for single user and then increment accordingly.

And also those user's are available in multiple table and all should share the same ID.

Ex : Table 1

```
ID           Name
875667       Test1
875667       Test1
875667       Test1
792380       Test2
792380       Test2
```

Need to update the ID like 111111 and then increment accordingly and also share the same ID in other tables

Ex : Table 2

```
ID           Name 
875667       Test1
875667       Test1
```

This should have same ID as table1 after updating ID - 111111

Please advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  If so, you can use updatable CTEs:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t1.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from [Database].[dbo].[table1] t1
     )
update toupdate
    set id = convert(nvarchar(255), 11111110 + seqnum);
```

Comment: I get this error - Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint, as id column is nvarchar.

Comment: add a cast: `set id = id + (cast(seqnum - 1 as nvarchar(20))`

Comment: can we set ID as - 11111111 and then increment accordingly rather incrementing with existing ID

Comment: @JP.  . . . With that information, you code makes a bit more sense.  I updated the answer so it should work for your purpose.

Comment: Is there a possibility to have the same ID across all tables while we update! kindly suggest

Comment: @JP. . . . If you want to share ids across tables, then sequences come to mind.  However, you might want to ask a *new* question with sample data and explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Eg - Table1 - after running the above query now user's have a new ID, but those user's are available in other table's as well so can we have the same ID as in table1 in all other table for that User ?